# jQuery Lightbox with proper back button support

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

After running some usability tests, I found that participants opened a [jQuery Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) to view larger images. Then rather than clicking the 'close' button they simply hit the browser back button. That sends them to the last page rather than closing the lightbox.

Does anyone know a jQuery photo gallery that supports the described back button behavior? Or has anyone modified their jQuery Lightbox to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the jQuery [history plugin here](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html). You will probably have to add some custom hook function to modify the behavior of Lightbox, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit weird to reply to question that was asked 5 years ago, but I released a gallery script that can do this - http://photoswipe.com/

Comment: Even 5 years later, such a library is very useful. Thanks for sharing, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I've got another solution for You.
Jquery mobile suports navigation controll.
Have a look at this link
[how to control back button event in Jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211984/how-to-control-back-button-event-in-jquery-mobile)