# How can I control the back button event in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, keycode

I tried to control back button, but I can’t. In here;

*[Take control of the hardware back button using jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859759/take-control-of-hardware-back-button-jquery-mobile)*

```
  event.keyCode == 27 // That’s for escape
  event.keyCode == 8 // That’s for backspace...it's also working on browser, but it doesn’t work on my tablet.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: [How to detect if the back button is pressed in mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39087816/1066234)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Recommended method `pagecontainerbeforechange`: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/detect-back-navigation/

---

You need to listen to the `navigation` event and `state.direction`.

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // Do something
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // Do something else
  }
});
```

**jQuery Mobile API:** [Navigation event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/navigate/)

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/UKJRM/)**

Comment: data.state.direction is undefined for me in Chrome (on desktop), but otherwise works great! Thanks

Comment: @JonathanBenn try this then https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/detect-back-navigation/

Comment: @Omar would you say it is better to use `pagecontainerbeforechange` over `navigate` since it has a wider scope?

Comment: @Adjit Yes, much better.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this **without [jQuery Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile)**

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
    if(e.oldURL.length > e.newURL.length)
        alert("back")
});
```

```html
<a href="#p2">goto page 2</a> and then use browser's navigation.</div>
```

And also [**Demo in CodePen**](https://codepen.io/bashirpour/pen/rgGgPZ).