# Back button physical

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, popup, back-button, back-button-control

I work on jquery mobile with phonegap 
I would like to detect a click on the physical back button to close my popup. 
Currently when I click on that button on a mobile support, it returns me to the page visited previously, I think it only uses the history.

If this is not possible in pure js, then maybe just block this physical button. 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18213393/1771795

Comment: i try it and not working on my mobile, always hash

Comment: I try with $("#mypopup").on(....          maybe the selector not firing (!= window) its possible with the focus ?

Comment: Are you adding `data-history="false"` or `true` to popup div?

Comment: nothing.. I forgot to mention that I work with phonegap

Comment: I just tried and it's not working,I also have a detection problem with the scroll, I think my event does not work