# Binding dynamically generated jQuery mobile elements to Javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have multiple pages in my jQuery mobile app and the "infamous" back button is being inserted dynamically; what I mean is that when the main page loads the back button does not show up on the second page in the DOM. As soon as I navigate to the second page jQuery mobile inserts the back button.

I am using the

```
 data-add-back-btn="true"
```

on the header div of the page to get the back button.

I want to run some of my own functions when the user clicks on the back button. My question is how can I target this dynamically generated content via JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'there should be button selector', function() { alert("Some additonal code"); });`

Comment: listen to `navigate` event http://stackoverflow.com/a/18213393/1771795