# Managing back button jquery mobile after loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on a jquery mobile hybrid app. as I have a fixed skeleton of the app, all I do is loading the content of each page on the `<div data-role="content">` of the index file preserving the header / footer / sidebar etc...

```
$("#pageContent").load ("pages/login-view.html", function () {
    $(this).enhanceWithin();
});
```

Everything's working just fine.

But what's blocking me right now, is managing the back action when clicking on a left arrow in the header.

Since I'm not reloading the whole page and I'm loading only the content on pages inside my main page, I have no Idea how to create or use the **Backstack** of loaded pages contents.

Do you hve any idea about how to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18213393/1771795 with some modifications of course. You need to listen to `navigate` and then do what you want to do on `pagecontainerbeforechange` or `pagecontainerbeforetransition`.

Comment: Thank you @Omar :) But using `$(window).` doesn't mean that the whole page changes ? because in my case only the content of a div does

Comment: it depends on the button, `data-rel="back"` and browser's back button will fire `navigate` event.

Comment: @Omar : hello omar, sorry for this delay. So in order to use `data-rel="back"` as it should be used, I need to change the whole page instead of changing only a block. so the browser can store the history pages on it's stack right ??

Comment: `data-rel=back` acts like browser's back button. Yes, all navigating actions are stored in history stack. If you want to navigate between divs (hidden/visible) you don't need `data-rel=back`, you can show/hide them.