# Add paraments to back button redirect to previous url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have this code that allows me to redirect the users on my current page to any other page when they click the back button

The code works fine but now I would like to pass the URLs parameters from the previous page to the redirected page so for example. Lets us say that the main page the user is on is `www.example.com/ready&val=1&base=2&timeid=3&rfid=4`

I would like the &val=1&base=2&timeid=3&rfid=4 passed on to the end of the domain that the user is being redirected to when they click the back button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(){
    var c_link = "www.example.com/time"; 
    var t;             
    try{
      for(t=0;10>t;++t)history.pushState({},"","#");
      onpopstate=function(t){t.state&&location.replace(c_link)}}
    catch(o){}
  }();
</script>
```

So the user gets to www.example.com/time I would like the `&val=1&base=2&timeid=3&rfid=4` to be and the end of it.

Comment: The back button only works on what is recorded in the web browser history. If a website could manipulate that, it would create serious security concerns. Image the hijacking that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use HTML5 `history.pushState` for this as it is not supported for IE9 and previous versions. But I can give you a better solution. You can use `sessionStorage` and `performance.navigation.type`.

---

`sessionStorage` is a storage type like `localStorage` but it only saves your data for the current tab.

Session storage can be used like this.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); //saves the value
sessionStorage.getItem('key'); //gets the saved value
```

---

`performance.navigation.type` is the browser is the variable that hold users navigation info.

```
if(performance.navigation.type == 2){
  //User is coming with back button
}
```

---

With the information above we can solve your problem easily.

Script on next page

```
var values = {
    val: 1,
    base: 2,
    timeid: 3,
    rfid: 4
}
sessionStorage.setItem('returnData', JSON.stringify(values))
```

Here is our main page.

```
if(performance.navigation.type == 2){
  var backValues = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('returnData'));
  //Do whatever you need with backValues
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var c_link = "www.example.com/time&val=1&base=2&timeid=3&rfid=4";
```

Please try to pas the value through the url  itself.

Comment: Those paraments may change they are not static. so every time time the usder visits the page they will be different

Comment: I want to take the parameters from from the current url and append them to redirected url

Comment: the script itself you can add the dynamic values . And the pass it on .what is your server side language ?