# javascript - Differentiate between browser close/back or forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

My requirement is to detect whether the browser is closed or refreshed or navigated(forward/back)

I am using `window.onbeforeunload` but it triggers for every click (even buttons,links). To suppress that I used this code to prevent its call on button clicks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:submit").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $("input:image").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $('a:not(a[href^=javascript])').click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

});
```

But now I need to distinguish between browser close and navigation or refresh. How can I achieve it?

**Edit**

I am doing some logic in my `window.onunload` event. For that I have a variable whose value needs to be assigned based on browser close/ navigation.

Comment: I'm not sure you can - as far as the page is concerned, it's being unloaded.  What's your [actual end goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Have a look over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211984/how-to-control-back-button-event-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: I have added what I want to achieve as an Edit to my question