# Use JavaScript/jQuery to detect the Android back button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

Currently I want to make a function to detect the Android back button is pressed and do some stuff on it.

1. The user opens the app, and clicks a button. This button lets the user to open a website.
2. The user fills in the information on page 2, and he/she wants to go back the previous page, and he/she clicks the back button on the Android phone.
3. The back button helps the user close the website and go back to my apps instead of back to page 1.

How can I do this with [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) or JavaScript to check the back button pressed by user? So that I can prevent the back button close the website, but redirect to another page.

**Is there a way to detect the browser Android back button event? I want to override the default setting of the Android back button, and add some code inside.**

*PS: Not using Java.*

- The back button on top (browser back button) can goes back to previous page.
- The back button on the bottom (back button phone) helps me close the website.
- I want make the bottom back button also goes back to the previous page.

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhOVn.jpg).

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far and why has it failed?

Comment: SO ain't a homework forum dude, show us your work and we'll help

Comment: Plus, it's a bad thing to override the behaviour of the system keys. If the user wants to go back, let them go back.

Comment: when you have opened a website in say, Chrome, when you press back, Chrome app will handle it, not your app

Comment: But I dun know how to detect the back button android on website.

Comment: If you are using cordova, please visit [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html) link. You can override device back button functionality

Comment: are you opening the website in your app itself or a browser ?

Comment: @mrid yes. I opening the website using my app.

Comment: May I know which scripting language are you using?

Comment: @androidOnHigh javascript jquery html. I want to know is jquery or javascript can detect android back button event?

Comment: @androidOnHigh For cordova, I use it to create apps. But the time I use my apps to open the website, it is not related to cordova anymore. I can detect back button in cordova but not in website.

Comment: did you found that how to get the event when user clicks bottom back button of a mobile

Answer (score 6):

You need to override the onBackPressed on WebView Activity and check if webview can go back or not.

```
@Overide
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webview.canGoBack())
        webview.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

<sub>Meta: When this answer was given, the question was not specific for *"JavaScript only"* and *"not coding in Java"*, etc.. i.e. handle only by the backend. This answer is strictly for the Android side, not for the backend side. I am keeping this answer if someone from Android need this answer.</sub>

Comment: @nitinkumarp yes i know this method. But I dont want Java. I did not down vote too.

Comment: When it can be easily handled by Android why you need JS code to detect Android back. Handled your Website back navigation and it will work as you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can also achieve it using JavaScript.

1. Use the below method or try to find deviceReady method.

   ```
    <body onload="onLoad()">
   ```
2. Put the below code in your main.js. This function will get call once body will get load.

   ```
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
   ```
3. On device ready is function which gets trigger once your device is ready.

   ```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
   ```
4. Once your ready, you can override your back button functionality.

   ```
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        // Do stuff here
    }
   ```

May I know is this what you was looking for?

*Or* you can use the `hashChange` event

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
    // ...
})
```

If you need to support older browsers, check out the [hashChange Event](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#hashchange-event) section on Modernizr's *HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills* wiki page.

Comment: This one works well in apps. But when the website is open, it cannot work. Like normally we did is if keycode == back, then it goes back. This one is for website. But how can I get the keycode of back button on android phone? So then I can do something on it.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please look once. You can check with hashChange event. I have added example also how to do it.

Comment: Nope. I saw this method but it does not fit my requirement.

Comment: Can you please check this [link](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/). Might be it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you should focus on the feature and not the device's implementation of that feature.

The Android Back Button has the same behavior as the browser back button.

As both react to the URL state you can control the behavior through the URL. You can achieve this through pushState. You can read about pushState from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) and here is a [CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/) article about using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **with JavaScript** and **without jQuery**

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
    if(e.oldURL.length > e.newURL.length)
        alert("back")
});
```

[**Demo in CodePen**](https://codepen.io/bashirpour/pen/rgGgPZ)

Source: *[How can I control the back button event in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211984/how-can-i-control-the-back-button-event-in-jquery-mobile/56233988#56233988)*

Comment: This requires at least one navigation, no? So it won't detect if back button was used right after the very first load of the page/app. Is there a way to cover that case too?

Comment: Maybe quickly navigating away and then back so that the page immediately has a navigation history or something like that... Could that work?