# How to handle Android back buttton with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android-webview, back-button-control

I'm making a WebView app for Android, using only HTML/CSS/JS, and i have to change the behaviour of the phone's back button in the navigation bar. (not the browser's back button.) How do i detect when the user clicks the back button of the phone and make my app do something? (WITH JAVASCRIPT.)

Comment: try the suggested answers here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092384/use-javascript-jquery-detect-android-back-button/47092587](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092384/use-javascript-jquery-detect-android-back-button/47092587), [Detect use of Android back button using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373849/detect-use-of-android-back-button-using-javascript).

Comment: "onpopstate" and "onhashchange" events are not working, and the other answer is Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onBackPressed` in the Android activity to call a JS function using [`webView.evaluateJavascript`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)):

```java
@Overide
public void onBackPressed() {
    webView.evaluateJavascript("window.doSomething()")
}
```

Then in your JS code, you can write the body of this `doSomething()` function. Make sure the function is exposed globally so that your Java code can access it like above.

For more advanced use cases, I'd recommend adopting [Capacitorjs](https://capacitorjs.com/) to your app, they have built a really robust system revolving the WebView techniques, and the migration process is rather simple and straightforward.