# Aadhaar masking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect a back button press on an `input` field. I've tried `e.key` and `e.which`, which is `undefined` in mobile Chrome. How can I get this to work? In desktop its working fine.

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured
  let aadhaar = "";
  let aadhaarStack = [];
  let maskStack = [];
  let flag = 0;

  $('#aadhaar').on('input', function(e) {
    let key = e.which || this.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
    console.log("here also")
    
    if (flag === 1) {
      console.log("here")
      aadhaarStack.pop();
      maskStack.pop();
    } else {
      key = String.fromCharCode(key);
      if (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length <= 11 && !isNaN(key)) {
        if (aadhaarStack.length > 1 && (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length) % 4 === 0) {
          aadhaarStack.push(" ");
          aadhaarStack.push(key);
          maskStack.push(" ");
          if (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length > 8) {
            maskStack.push(key);
          } else {
            maskStack.push("X");
          }
        } else {
          aadhaarStack.push(key);
          if (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length > 8) {
            maskStack.push(key);
          } else {
            maskStack.push("X");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    updateUi();
  });

  function updateUi() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      aadhaar = maskStack.join("");
      $('#aadhaar').val(aadhaar);
    }, 100);
  }

  $('#aadhaar').on('keydown', function(e) {
    alert(e.key);
    let key = e.which || this.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
    if (key === 8 || key === 46 || e.key === 'Backspace') {
      flag = 1;
    } else {
      flag = 0;
    }
    console.log("first here")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxliength="14" id="aadhaar" autocomplete="off" />
```

Here is the JSBin link https://jsbin.com/rogepevutu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213393/2943218

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to control back button event in Jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211984/how-to-control-back-button-event-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: From the behaviour of the code it looks like you're simply trying to hide the user input with `X` characters. As such, why not just use a `type="password"` input...?

Comment: Also note that `maxliength` needs to be changed to `maxlength`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its not only changing characters it adding spaces after for every four characters and also last 4 characters should be visible

Comment: @FDisk that's regarding handling back button behaviour in the jQuery Mobile library. In this case the OP means the delete key when using the standard jQuery library on a mobile device.

Comment: its kind of credit card number masking. i just need to figure out backspace press on mobile devices.

Comment: Do you actually need to add the spaces to the value entered by the user? That seems a needless over-complication. It makes more sense to accept the value without any spaces. Then you can add the spaces *only* where the value is displayed in the UI.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan probably u r correct maybe we can do that too. but how do i find the back button press in mobile devices

Comment: Detecting keypresses on mobile device keyboards is notoriously unreliable. This is why I would strongly suggest you use a different approach

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if we can detect other keypresses then why can't back button press. I hope there has to be a way.

Comment: check this https://keycode.info/

Comment: @FDisk i tried it in desktop it is working in mobile it is unidentified

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan u r right detecting keyboard presses on mobile devices unreliable. I thought v can do it, but I was wrong. Thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to handle back press as this solution is not reliable.
My solution is to try comparing the length of the prev and current, and you perform your task based on that.

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured
  let aadhaar = "";
  let aadhaarStack = [];
  let maskStack = [];
  let flag = 0;

  $('#aadhaar').on('input', function(e) {
    let key = e.which || this.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);    
    if (this.value.length < aadhaarStack.length) {
      aadhaarStack.pop();
      maskStack.pop();
    } else {
      key = String.fromCharCode(key);
      if (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length <= 11 && !isNaN(key)) {
        if (aadhaarStack.length > 1 && (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length) % 4 === 0) {
          aadhaarStack.push(" ");
          aadhaarStack.push(key);
          maskStack.push(" ");
          if (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length > 8) {
            maskStack.push(key);
          } else {
            maskStack.push("X");
          }
       } else {
         aadhaarStack.push(key);
         if (aadhaarStack.filter(i => i !== " ").length > 8) {
         maskStack.push(key);
       } else {
         maskStack.push("X");
       }
    }
  }
}

  updateUi();
});

function updateUi() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    aadhaar = maskStack.join("");
    $('#aadhaar').val(aadhaar);
  }, 100);
 }
});
```

Comment: Amazing this is what I am looking for awesome bro thanks 

Answer (score -1):

Our Masking Solution is based on Computer Vision, OCR, deep learning frameworks to serve the purpose of aadhar card masking for real-life unstructured data. Process your customer’s Aadhaar in seconds, and mask your documents like humans.

https://textck.com/digitalonboarding/aadhaar-masking/